# The setting to connect one router to another, how?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

I want to be able to watch Netflix outside US via Chromecast, and for this, [I will need to setup some static route rules](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=49060386&postcount=283).

For this purpose I bought a second router, my Internet-modem-router connection looks like below.

[image]

The twist is that for router 1, I don't intend for any computers to connect to it, I only want the router 1 to connect to the modem by providing username/password via PPPoE.

Instead, I want all of my devices to be connected to router 2, because at router 2 I will configure all the static routing rules, the DNS server and everything.

I read that I would need to disable [the second router DHCP in order for this to work](http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-One-Router-to-Another-to-Expand-a-Network). Besides that, is there any other setting that I should do to router 1 and router 2 so that the Internet connection can work in my house?

PS: I know it is vastly simpler to do away with router 2, and configure router 1 with all the static route rules, but let's assume that I don't want to do this, because

1. For some weird reasons I need to use router 1
2. And Router 1 doesn't support static route rules, so I would need a second router for the rules.

Comment: Is the second router connected wirelessly or with an Ethernet cable

Comment: Connect with Ethernet cable

Comment: Set the ip of the second router, turn dhcp off, make it's gateway the ip of router one and connect the Ethernet cable between one of the four ports don't use the internet port

Comment: This will enable you to connect to router two but have router one assign the ip addresses

Comment: If you need more detailed instructions lmk I'll post an answer with specifics cause my setuo is exactly the same

Comment: @CheeseConQueso, please do post an answer with more specific info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Router one:

IP - 192.168.1.1

DHCP - enabled with range 192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.120

(You can define a smaller range, depends on how many devices will connect)

Router two:

IP - 192.168.1.2

DHCP - disabled

Connect Ethernet cable from  router one to router two on any of the ports except the internet port.

With this setup, you can connect to router one or router two and the ip will be assigned by router one.